# create flat faced edge

Tags: edges, bevel

im relatively new to using blender and i was wondering if anyone could help me find the quickest way to create a flat face on an odd angle with more than 3 vertexes. Here is an example of what im looking to achieve. (This was done by putting a cube up to the corner and using Boolean to delete the corner) any help would be awesome :D

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If face is not yet created, you can use :

- booleans, as you used it in example, probably the fastest way. 2 different manners :

  - [intersect](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/faces.html#intersect-boolean), used in edit mode
  - [modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/generate/booleans.html), used in object mode
- [knife or knife project](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/subdividing/knife_subdivide.html) could do the job too

If face already exist, in edit mode and with face selected, you can :

- mesh > clean up > [make planar faces](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/cleanup.html#make-planar-faces)
- set the 3D manipulator to normal orientation and make a Z scale of 0 (<kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>)

Note that the last 2 ways affect the topology around the face.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the **Mesh > Bisect** operation for this.

Just look from the side angle you want to cut from, draw a line over your geometry with LClick+Drag, and release.

[image: Mesh Bisect in action]

There are some settings in the Operator Panel. Enable **Fill** and **Clear Outer** to get the cut to produce a face like in the GIF above.

[image: Mesh Bisect Operator Panel Settings]

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use [Bevel](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/subdividing/bevel.html) tool in Edit mode and then [dissolve](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/basics/deleting.html#dissolve) middle edge to cut that face quickly:

[image: beveling-corner]

However note that if dissolving you get big Ngon (face consisting of more than 4 vertices) which might create problems afterwards even if it's flat. Depending on the purpose this mesh is created for it might be better to split that face into triangle and quad or change the mesh design.